# Installing gearman with libdrizzle on mac osx

Tags: macos, gearman, libdrizzle

Anyone could install gearman with libdrizzle enabled for mac os?
I'm using mac ports but it fails to install it with libdrizzle enabled

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the following?

```
$ sudo port install gearmand +drizzle
```

Can you provide an error message or some more information to pinpoint your issue?